# Weird JSON mapping issue with Set - missing an element

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, objectmapper

Here is a simple Java code to test my issue:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String s = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"fsgh\",\n" +
            "      \"email\": \"dfgh@qwe.qwe\",\n" +
            "      \"password\": \"fdg\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"sdfg\",\n" +
            "      \"email\": \"zxc@zxc.sd\",\n" +
            "      \"password\": \"dfghfgh\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]";
String jsonBody = "{\n" +
            "  \"id\": \"\",\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"<cxzzx\",\n" +
            "  \"email\": \"asd@asd.com\",\n" +
            "  \"address\": \"asd 72b\",\n" +
            "  \"zip\": \"1234\",\n" +
            "  \"city\": \"Asdf\",\n" +
            "  \"country\": \"Norway\",\n" +
            "  \"enabled\": \"true\",\n" +
            "  \"quota\": \"50\",\n" +
            "  \"expires\": \"2021-04-02\",\n" +
            "  \"adminAccounts\": " +
            s +
            "}";
Set<Account> accounts = mapper.readValue(s, Set.class);
Organization organization = mapper.readValue(jsonBody, Organization.class);
```

Now you can see from the json that we should have 2 admin accounts and the accounts object is correct but the organization only has the first one. Here is a screenshot of the values in the debugger:
[image: From debugger]

Anyone has any ideas where this might be coming from?

Comment: How are AdminAccount (or whatever the class is called)'s equals/hashCode implemented? I noticed both accounts have an empty id. If an account's equality is based on id, then the HashSet will (correctly) omit one as a duplicate.

Comment: @yshavit It is not implemented in the Account class and I believe that would also be valid for the "accounts" Set that has (correctly) both elements

Comment: Ah, good point. What does the one element in adminAccount look like? Does it give any clue as to what's going on?

Comment: @yshavit It is the exact same element as the first one from the accounts set. If I have more than 2, I get the complete set in "accounts" but always only the first one in the organization object

Comment: Can you add your POJO classes and tell us what version of Jackson you are using? This seems to be working for me.

Comment: @Adam the pojos are almost exactly the same as the ones described bellow except that the adminAccounts is a Set instead of a List and Jackson version is 2.8.4

Comment: Are you saying your `Organization` class has `adminAccounts` as a `List`? Because your debugger seems to indicate it is a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you **NOT** to use string concatenation because jackson provides feasibility to achieve this with pojos. Its clean and less error prone.

First Declare a pojo for Account

```
public class Account {

private String id;

private String name;

private String email;

private String password;


public Account(String id, String name, String email, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Then for Organization. Note that we include list of admin accounts here

```
public class Organization {

private String id;

private String email;

private String name;

private String address;

private String zip;

private String city;

private String country;

private boolean enabled;

private int quota;

private String expires;

private List<Account> adminAccounts;

public Organization(String id, String email, String name, String address, String zip, String city, String country, boolean enabled, int quota, String expires, List<Account> adminAccounts) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.quota = quota;
    this.expires = expires;
    this.adminAccounts = adminAccounts;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public int getQuota() {
    return quota;
}

public void setQuota(int quota) {
    this.quota = quota;
}

public String getExpires() {
    return expires;
}

public void setExpires(String expires) {
    this.expires = expires;
}

public List<Account> getAdminAccounts() {
    return adminAccounts;
}

public void setAdminAccounts(List<Account> adminAccounts) {
    this.adminAccounts = adminAccounts;
}
}
```

Then we come to the actual business logic. You create any number of accounts you need

```
Account account1 = new Account("1", "name1", "email1", "pass1");
Account account2 = new Account("2", "name2", "email2", "pass2");
```

And add them to a list

```
 List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
 accounts.add(account1);
 accounts.add(account2);
```

Then add them to the Organization

```
Organization organization = new Organization("orgId", "orgEmail", "orgName", "orgAddress", "OrgZip", "orgCity", "orgCountry", true, 50, "2017-3-3", accounts);
```

Basically, your String s is represented by accounts and jsonBody represented by organization. Try to create these two account pojos first and organization and manipulate them as java objects

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tested with in order to get this to work. I am using `jackson-databind-2.8.6`. I suspect there is something strange with your POJO classes or there may be a bug in the version of Jackson you are using:

```
public class JacksonTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
      final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      final String s = "[\n" +
         "    {\n" +
         "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
         "      \"name\": \"fsgh\",\n" +
         "      \"email\": \"dfgh@qwe.qwe\",\n" +
         "      \"password\": \"fdg\"\n" +
         "    },\n" +
         "    {\n" +
         "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
         "      \"name\": \"sdfg\",\n" +
         "      \"email\": \"zxc@zxc.sd\",\n" +
         "      \"password\": \"dfghfgh\"\n" +
         "    }\n" +
         "  ]";
      final String jsonBody = "{\n" +
         "  \"id\": \"\",\n" +
         "  \"name\": \"<cxzzx\",\n" +
         "  \"email\": \"asd@asd.com\",\n" +
         "  \"address\": \"asd 72b\",\n" +
         "  \"zip\": \"1234\",\n" +
         "  \"city\": \"Asdf\",\n" +
         "  \"country\": \"Norway\",\n" +
         "  \"enabled\": \"true\",\n" +
         "  \"quota\": \"50\",\n" +
         "  \"expires\": \"2021-04-02\",\n" +
         "  \"adminAccounts\": " + s +
         "}";

      final Set<Account> accounts = mapper.readValue(s, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(Set.class, Account.class));
      System.out.println("Accounts Size: " + accounts.size());
      System.out.println("Accounts: " + accounts);

      System.out.println();

      final Organization organization = mapper.readValue(jsonBody, Organization.class);
      System.out.println("Organization Admin Accounts Size: " + organization.adminAccounts.size());
      System.out.println("Organization Admin Accounts: " + organization.adminAccounts);
   }

   private static class Account {
      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Account [id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", email=" + this.email + ", password=" + this.password + "]";
      }

      public String id, name, email, password;
   }

   private static class Organization {
      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Organization [id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", email=" + this.email + ", address=" + this.address + ", zip=" +
            this.zip + ", city=" +
            this.city + ", country=" + this.country + ", enabled=" + this.enabled + ", quota=" + this.quota + ", expires=" + this.expires +
            ", adminAccounts=" +
            this.adminAccounts + "]";
      }

      public String id, name, email, address, zip, city, country, enabled, quota, expires;
      public Set<Account> adminAccounts;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it, for s, This array has only one element, s = "[object1]" and object1 has two elements, so accounts.size() = 2, organization.adminAccounts=s="[object1]", organization.adminAccounts.size()=1, organization.adminAccounts is just has object1. You want organization.adminAccounts.size()=2, organization.adminAccounts="[[object2], [object3]]", so s = "[[object2],[object3]]".
 You can try this:

```
String s = "[\n" +
      "    [{\n" +
      "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
      "      \"name\": \"fsgh\",\n" +
      "      \"email\": \"dfgh@qwe.qwe\",\n" +
      "      \"password\": \"fdg\"\n" +
      "    }],\n" +
      "    [{\n" +
      "      \"id\": \"\",\n" +
      "      \"name\": \"sdfg\",\n" +
      "      \"email\": \"zxc@zxc.sd\",\n" +
      "      \"password\": \"dfghfgh\"\n" +
      "    }]\n" +
      "  ]";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S9QR.png)